# jquery : delete parent if the child empty

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a leftmenu with lists but some of this lists are empty for backend

the code :

```html
<ul>
    <li id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span><span class="mtext">
                Etudiant
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-option="off">
            <span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span><span class="mtext">
                PRE-Inscription
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul id="sub" class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="LINK">
                    XXXXXX
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span><span class="mtext">
                planning
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span><span class="mtext">
                Concours
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
        ....
</ul>
```

if there is a ul inside the li that's means is not empty what i want to do is delete or remove empty  list and thanks

Comment: Have you tried to resolve this yourself? If so, could you please update your question with what you have tried and why it didn't work? If not, please give it a shot and come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(".dropdown").each(function(i, obj){    
     if ($(this).children("ul").length == 0) {
         $(this).remove();
     }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`isNotEmpty()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-isnotempty) method on the collection, for example let's assume that you have a dropdown of a user and each user may or may not have multiple posts

You can use Blade directives to achieve this

```html
<li id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-option="off">
        <span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span><span class="mtext">User Name
        </span>
        {{ $user->name }}
    </a>
    @if($user->posts()->isNotEmpty())
    <ul id="sub" class="submenu">
        @foreach ($user->posts as $post)
        <li>
            <a href="LINK">
                {{ $post->title }}
            </a>
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    @endif
</li>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the issue is delete li which has id and class = dropdown

Comment: Adapt the solution to your needs, I didn't write code for you to copy-paste